# Make sure transaction will be in block x

Tags: gas, bsc, arbitrage, bot

I am currently building a frontrunning bot for the Binance Smart Chain.

The problem: Sometimes my transaction is getting into the block I want, sometimes I miss the block by some ms I guess

My question: Is there a way to make sure, that my transaction will be 100% in the block I want the transaction to be in? I hope so, because a frontrunning bot with a 50% success rate isnt that good haha

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can't really force the transaction to be included in certain block (especially in BSC which doesn't have MEV), but you can revert the transaction if it's in a wrong block. You can use the `block.number`: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties

So something like: `if (block.number != 123) { revert(); }`